# Multiple Markers in GoogleMaps Javascript+Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, json, laravel-5.1

I am trying to build a simple "storelocator" where I pass the search key and return the nearby address on the map. For this I am using Javascript and Laravel Eloquent. I am able to see the map but not the markers. Please suggest me what should I do?

```
 <script>
  var locations =  <?php echo $address_markes ?>  ;
  var lat = 22.54430389404;
  var lng = 88.36476135254;
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),{
    center:{
      lat: lat,
      lng: lng
    },
    zoom: 15
  });

  var marker, i;

  for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
      })(marker, i));
    }
  /*var marker =  new google.maps.Marker({
    position:{
      lat:lat,
      lng: lng
    },
    map:map
  });*/

  </script>
```

when I click on view source, I see this :

> ```
> <script>   
>     var locations =  [{
>         "dealership_name":"Shyam Motors",
>         "lat":22.544303894,
>         "lng":88.3647613525
>     },
>     {
>         "dealership_name":"Das Auto",
>         "lat":22.5396156311,
>         "lng":88.3710708618
>     }]  ;   
>     var lat = 22.54430389404;   
>     var lng = 88.36476135254;   
>     var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),{
>         center:{
>           lat: lat,
>           lng: lng
>         },
>         zoom: 15   
>     });
>
> var marker, i;
>
> for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
>     marker = new google.maps.Marker({
>         position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
>     map: map
>     });
>
>   google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
>     return function() {
>       infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
>       infowindow.open(map, marker);
>     }
>   })(marker, i));
> }   /*var marker =  new google.maps.Marker({
> position:{
>   lat:lat,
>   lng: lng
> },
> map:map   });*/
>  </script>
> ```

So where am I going wrong ? Please guide.

Comment: Did you try `console.log(locations);`? What does it show

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you doing wrong is; that you try to get item from objects through an index. When you would try `console.log(locations[i])` within your for-loop you would see something like this:

```
{
    dealership_name: "Shyam Motors",
    lat: "22.544303894",
    lng: "88.3647613525",
}
```

After all this is basic javascript, if don't know it you should learn it.

This is how your for-loop should look like:

```
for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i].lat, locations[i].lng),
        map: map
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
            infowindow.setContent(locations[i].dealership_name);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
    })(marker, i));
}
```

Comment: Well that was a perfect solution. Thank you. And yes. I am a newbie. Where do you think I should start ? I am from a programming background however, no experience in web based scripts.

Comment: You could do a few quick courses: [here](https://www.codeschool.com/paths/javascript) and/or [here](https://www.codecademy.com/learn/javascript)